# How to resolve error converting bytecode to dex?

Tags: java, android

when I run the app in the android studio with press F5 I have seen the error you can see the error on this link![screenshot error][1]
how can I resolve it?

Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
defaultConfig {
   ...       
}
...

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha7'
compile 'ir.adad.androidsdkv3:AdadSDKv3:3.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: 
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: 
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: 
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing java 
process with main class com.android.dx.command.Main with arguments {--dex --
num-threads=4 --output
```

Comment: show your gradle file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable Multidex in your app.gradle

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
    }    
}
```

Comment: @MasihKolahdouzan share your `build.gradle`